# Is there a term for grief triggered from merely seeing, or remembering, places that a griever enjoyed with loved ones?

Tags: depression

***The loved ones don't have to be dead. The may simply be too ill or senile.***  The griever may be [anticipating grief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticipatory_grief). I am not asking about nostalgia or wistfulness  — the bleakness, forlornness are much gloomier here.

Consider an adult who — whenever he happens upon, or remembers, a  venue that he as a child used to frequent with his parent — instantly gets sad and doleful because he no longer is a child, and his parent is much older. Examples can be past homes of theirs where they lived happily together, schools where his parents took him,  places of recreation (a shopping mall or park or restaurant) that they frequented, and even streets and roads that they walked and drove together on. Upon sight, the same location triggers the adult to forthwith VIVIDLY remember and envision his parents with him. But then the adult saddens, because those memories hailed from a happier time. Perhaps now they can no longer enjoy those shared memories in the same way, shape, or form with their parents. Perhaps the aging parent can no longer be physical, walk, move, or drive. ***Again, the parent may still be alive.***

Further, consider a graver case where the adult cannot even bear or stomach seeing, revisiting or even envisaging these places. I have heard of patients who must muster up the courage to move to a new city, simply because almost everywhere in their old community triggers them to envision and remember themselves  with their loved ones  — and these envisages and remembrances  trigger too much disconsolateness and grief!

My question may be similar to — but ISN'T —  [Is it okay to move away from a town or area because you have a lot of bad memories associated with it?](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-okay-to-move-away-from-a-town-or-area-because-you-have-a-lot-of-bad-memories-associated-with-it) [Has moving to another city/state ever helped you get out of your depression/anxiety?](https://www.quora.com/Has-moving-to-another-city-state-ever-helped-you-get-out-of-your-depression-anxiety?shared=1) [Should I leave a city when there are too many bad memories and toxic circle of friends?](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-leave-a-city-when-there-are-too-many-bad-memories-and-toxic-circle-of-friends?shared=1)

Why not? Because my question involves a clear determinate cause of the grief and woe — seeing or remembering places that you experienced with loved ones in the past.

I apologize if I am rambling, but I am unschooled in psychology and do not know the correct terms. Please do not hesitate to edit and improve my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desiderium, saudade.

[Desiderium](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/emotions-17th18th/LD1Background.html) being dragged into English by Thomas Aquinas from the works of Aristotle: an intense desire or longing for that which is lost (such as a time) which may never be regained.

[Saudade](https://en.psychologyinstructor.com/saudade-a-deep-emotional-state/) being adopted from Portuguese, first usage uncertain: a profound melancholic longing for someone or something cared about or loved, again carrying repressed knowledge that the object of longing may never be had again.

> The suffering coming from a happy memory.